# Add Fonts to PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

How can I add more fonts in PL/SQL Developer?  Should I use the font.properties file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the fonts used in various windows (in particular the various browsers, editors, and grids), click on Tools, then Preferences, then click on the Fonts entry in the User Interface section of the Preferences dialog.  To change a font for a particular item click on the Select button for the item you wish to change and make your changes.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

For use new (custom fonts) you should add ttf-file to C:\Windows\Fonts. It's not enough to add font to Settings -> Personalization -> Fonts.